# Вертикальное выезжающего меню с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, меню

Создал выпадающее вниз меню, работающее на jQuery. Но ошибка в том, что кнопка, которая должна последовать за открывающейся частью меню, "опаздывает" за ней, то есть не следует в одно и то же время за нижней частью. Хотя время анимации совпадает со временем открытия меню. Также, хотелось бы узнать, как вернуть кнопку в обратное положение при закрытии меню.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav').hide();
  $('#menu').click(function() {
    $("nav").slideToggle(1000);
    $('#menu').animate({
      top: "220px"
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#menu {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="menu">Open<br>This</button>
<nav>
  <a>Страница 1</a>
  <hr>
  <a>Страница 2</a>
  <hr>
  <a>Страница 3</a>
  <hr>
  <a>Страница 4</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может сделать чтобы кнопка позиционировалась в зависимости от контента выше?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav').hide();
  $('#menu').click(function() {
    $("nav").slideToggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
#menu {
  margin-top:20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a>Страница 1</a>
  <hr>
  <a>Страница 2</a>
  <hr>
  <a>Страница 3</a>
  <hr>
  <a>Страница 4</a>
</nav>
<button id="menu">Open<br>This</button>
```

Comment: Классно) поставил +1.

Comment: Решение оказалось банально простым, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Не трогайте кнопку вообще. Просто перенесите ее по меню

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav').hide();
  $('#menu').click(function() {
    $("nav").slideToggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <a>Страница 1</a>
  <hr>
  <a>Страница 2</a>
  <hr>
  <a>Страница 3</a>
  <hr>
  <a>Страница 4</a>
</nav>
<button id="menu">Open<br>This</button>
```